# Haskell function and let statement

Tags: haskell

In GHCi, I can do following:

```
ghci> let ddd n = [0..n]
ghci> ddd 10
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

However, if I define similar function in a file as :

```
ddd :: Int -> [a]
ddd n = [0..n]
```

After loading the file in GHCi, I got following error

```
ghci> :l dsp.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( dsp.hs, interpreted )

dsp.hs:43:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Int'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for ddd :: Int -> [a] at dsp.hs:42:8
    In the expression: n
    In the expression: [0 .. n]
    In an equation for `ddd': ddd n = [0 .. n]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any reason??

Thanks

Comment: One way to debug these types of errors is to remove the explicit type declaration and use the `:t` command in ghci to see what type the compiler deduces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are returning a list of `[a]` and not `[Int]`, this should work:

```
ddd :: Int -> [Int]
ddd n = [0..n]
```

Or if you want a more generic solution:

```
ddd :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
ddd n = [0..n]
```

Comment: The most generic sensible solution is actually `dd :: Enum a => a -> [a]` with `ddd n = [(toEnum 0)..n]`, which can also be written less clearly as `ddd = enumFromTo $ toEnum 0`

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, but I doubt if that will be useful for any types other than types of `Num` instances. `dd 'a'` produces a garbled output actually.

Comment: that's because a whole bunch of characters before `a` are control characters. But `ddd (100::Natural)` makes perfect sense, although naturals lack `negate` and are therefore not in `Num`.

Comment: I have the feeling there may even be an efficiency reason to do it my way in some sufficiently polymorphic situations—yours requires one dictionary for `fromInteger`and a second for `enumFromTo`, whereas mine specializes the `0` to `Int` and uses the same dictionary for both `toEnum` and `enumFromTo`. I'm not *sure* that makes a difference, but my sense is it might.

Answer (score 3):

If we enable the `ExplicitForAll` extension, we can see that the type signature you gave is the same as

```
ddd :: forall a. Int -> [a]
```

The `forall` is implied if it isn't written out, but the `ExplicitForAll` extension makes it, well, explicit.

But, this isn't the case! Your definition doesn't work *for all* types `a`, just for one specific type: `Int`. So the correct signature is `Int -> [Int]`.

Comment: While I don't think bringing up `forall` is effective, I do enjoy making the counter-question to these types of misunderstandings.  Questions such as: What is the literal `0` when given my type `Opaque`?  Notice I am not telling you anything about type `Opaque`... good luck.

Comment: Is `ExplicitForAll` a good idea these days? If you use it and later decide you need `ScopedTypeVariables`, mightn't you have to go around and do a bunch of renaming?

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't intent to suggest its use, I was just using it to make the point that there is always an implicit `forall` by making it explict.